# WordPress page content in Modal Pop-Up

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog

I am working on a WordPress gallery website which has only three pages: Home, Gallery, and Bio (http://adamgreener.com/).

When you click Bio, the Bio content pops up, powered by **Easy Modal** plugin (the content is manually typed in HTML in the plugin settings).

I also have the exact same HTML content in a WordPress page (which mobile viewers see, rather than a popup).

The page is very simple to edit, but the Modal content is not so friendly to the average user. I am seeking a way that I can allow the user to edit only the Bio page, and have that modal content update at the same time.

What would be the best route for such an action?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`get_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) to get the page content, and a shortcode to display it in the popup. In the `functions.php` file of your WordPress theme, e.g.:

```
add_action( 'init', 'greener_shortcode_init', 11 );
function greener_shortcode_init()
{
    add_shortcode( 'greener_bio', 'greener_bio_shortcode' );
}

function greener_bio_shortcode( $atts )
{
    $page_id = 123; // the ID of the Bio page
    $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
    $return = '';
    $return .= '<h2>' . $page_data->post_title . '</h2>';
    $return .= $page_data->post_content;
    return $return;
}
```

Then, in your modal, use the shortcode:

`[greener_bio]`

Comment: This sounds like a super-simple solution. However, it throws a fatal error when I try to put this in the functions.php page, saying it calls an undefined function.

PHP is not my strongest point. Thanks for your help, diggy.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in /nfs/c09/h04/mnt/140053/domains/adamgreener.com/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3871

Comment: Hmmm.. A bit weird, I tested on my local install and it works perfectly fine. Try hooking the `add_shortcode`function into `init`, I edited my answer.

Comment: Did you replace `123` with the correct page ID? Also, you might try to replace the line `$return .= apply_filters( 'the_content', $page_data->post_content );` with `$return .= $page_data->post_content;`, 'cause I think the modal applies the filter for you.

Comment: To be sure, the code should be inserted in the `functions.php` file of your WordPress theme, not in `wp-includes/functions.php`

Comment: BOOM! That did the trick. I thought I had placed it in the correct functions page. Unfortunately, I got my local copies screwed up. Thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways to accomplish what you're going for, both described in depth in my blog post: https://allurewebsolutions.com/open-wordpress-post-modal-without-plugin

You can also just use my plugin for this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-modal/

## First Method

The first method requires modifying the template that serves the content you want to appear in the modal. For example, you have a template called `modal-content-template.php`.

Inside that template we wrap the content we want loaded into the modal with:

```
<?php if (!$_GET) { ?>
    // content that gets loaded on mobile
<?php } ?>
```

Full example of a template where we are excluding the WordPress header and footer:

```
<?php if (!$_GET) { get_header(); } ?>

<article>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <h1 class="page-title"></h1>

  <section class="entry-content cf">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </section>

</article>

<?php if (!$_GET) { get_footer(); } ?>
```

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/allurewebsolutions/pen/mVyaxZ) for the JS required to make this work

## Second Method

The second method is a little more elegant. We use the `modalContent.load(post_link + ' #modal-ready');` method to load the modal content.

The modal contact is wrapped in a wrapper container with ID `#modal-ready`. This can be done without even touching the page template using a function that hooks into the content.

```
add_action('the_content', 'wrap_content');
function wrap_content($content)
{
    return '<div id="modal-ready">' . $content . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your plugin but in the plugin's settings I can only target the links based on the element ID and not the class.